# Call a class of a jar from SSJS xPages

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I would like to ask a question about using Java classes in SSJS (Server Side JavaScript) on xPages. I created a simple Java class "HelloWorld" and exported it to a jar file. Then I tried to call it from SSJS on an xPage but with no success. These are some things that I tried:

1. Added the jar to the build path of the .nsf (both jar and nsf were local)
2. Added the jar to WEB_INF/lib folder of the nsf.
3. Called the class of the jar directly from SSJS as

   var a = new com.myself.testJava.HelloWorld();
4. Called the class from another Java class that I created in the nsf and then call the second class from SSJS.

I always get an error 500 "HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception"

I have also tried to run my xpage on a server and add the jar file to the jvm/lib/ext folder. In this case the error was "com" not found, which I understand that it means that the class cannot be found.

I have accomplished to create a java class in the nsf and then call from SSJS, but I want to be able to use 3rd party classes.

Could you please give any information about what are the correct steps?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Adding a JAR to WEB-INF/lib works for me w/o any problems...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the top of your SSJS you will need to do an ImportPackage.

```
importPackage(com.myself.testJava)
```

Note that you need to import the package and not the class. Now the rest of your SSJS should work.

Comment: Thank you Declan! I added importPackage and it worked! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It look like there is some error in Your class - maybe unresolved compilation problem?

Please check out what is logged in xpages logs files on server.

You should be able to find the exception (with full stack) in file error-log-0.xml in 
'\Data\domino\workspace\logs' folder.

Comment: I tried with the jar of JavaMail API too, to be sure that it wasn't a problem of my jar. I should have added importPackage as @Declan Lynch pointed out.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that importPackage is not obligatory. I'm using full qualified names all around my app they work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

All those should work but may require some fine tuning.

Try your **2.** and place the JAR in build path with Domino Designer: Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add JARs.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but it seems the problem was I had to add importPackage to SSJS code.

Comment: Interesting. I don't use it usually. Imports are optional just like in Java.