# Intellisense (or Eclispse equivalent) in xPages Javascript for managed beans?

Tags: xpages

I wrote a managed bean and have succesfully incorported into an xPage.  What I noticed is the intellisense (or whatevver it is called in Eclipse), does not work for the managed bean.   Is there anyway to get that to work?

Comment: Do you mean content assistance (displaying a list of available methods associated with the current object)? If so, no. The SSJS editor is aware of the base set of classes that comprise the JVM itself, but doesn't automatically discover classes that you add to your project (unlike the Java editor). All SSJS really is Java, just with a weird syntax and woefully inadequate editor. Ideally, all references to beans should be expressed within prefixless EL anyway.

Comment: Eclipse standard has this functionality as long as you have WTP installed.  I'm not sure the plausibility of getting WTP installed into Domino Designer though.

Comment: @TobySamples Designer is based on 3.4. WTP in 3.4 was very much in its infancy. Once Designer breaks its Expeditor shackles it will contain a current WTP

Comment: I am Looking forward to that and many other newer Eclipse features.

Comment: Did you try importPackage? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701583/call-a-class-of-a-jar-from-ssjs-xpages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not yet. This is on the development 2do list, but it is not "over the waterline" (agile lingo for "feature actually worked on")